# Library items are not protected from the Administrator users

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

Currently, in the Spotfire Library, our clients store their Analysis files in a folder which is not visible to other clients (i.e. users) because their account is set as the owner of the folder. However, if I, as a developer, log in with Administrator account, I am able to see and open all of our client's Analysis files.

is there any security measures I can implement so that our client's Analysis files, stored in the Spotfire Library, are not accessible even for Administrator accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached to TIBCO about that, and it turns out that this feature does not exist as of now. If anyone is interested, please upvote it here -> https://ideas.tibco.com/ideas/TS-I-7252